# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name Borderless.Colored

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I have update android support library yesterday, and now I am getting this error while building my project. I have searched for solutions and found nothing useful.

Here is what I have in my `build.gradle` file

```
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
  minSdkVersion 15
  targetSdkVersion 23
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
```

Comment: some resources are removed in the new API so try to use any alternative ,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change compilesdk and build tool version to 25.

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
```

Comment: @mallaudin how you fixed it? I have faced same problem and solved it by using my answer. Is there any effective way to solve it?

Comment: I did the same. I had to go on with latest versions.